# Prove $f(x)=3x+1$ is continuous at $x=a$

Tags: calculus

**Question:**
Give the formal definition for a function to be continuous at $x=a$.

Prove, by using the formal definition, that $f(x)=3x+1$ is continuous at $x=a$, where a is any point on the real line.

I am able give the formal definition which is:
 For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ (which depends on $\epsilon$) such that:

$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ wherever, $0<|x-a|<\delta(\epsilon)$
However, I am not sure how to go about the second part without a value for $L$, would anybody be able to help?

Comment: Which value of $L$ would be very logical?

Comment: Also that's not the definition of continuity in $a$. $L$ takes a very special value in the definition.

Comment: Oh I see, maybe that's where I'm going wrong, what is the definition of continuity in a?

Comment: Well, since you asked this question, the definition should be somewhere in your course notes or textbook, go take a look, think about it and try to solve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have cited the definition of the limit when $x$ tends to $a$; Continuity implies $L = f(a)$. Then, it is only a matter of proving the limit by epsilon-delta, which I assume that you are confident with
$$
 0<|x - a|<\delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| = |3x+1 - 3a - 1| < \varepsilon, \qquad x \in \mathbf{R}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, L=f(a) is somewhat missing from my course notes!